# what happens when add to classpath in eclipse or intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, classpath

Can somebody please explain what happens when add some jars to classpath in eclipse or intellij. Is this classpath only for this project/application/jvm?
Thanks.

I know it's for the application to be able to use classes in the jars. What I don't understand is what this classpath is. Is it the same as the classpath in the system environment variables? Is this classpath only for this project/application/jvm? Is it possible for other projects/applications to use this classpath?

I'm working on a project which is based on Grails. And I saw this line in the configuration file.

```
<import resources="classpath:META-INF/............xml" />
```

What is the classpath here?

Comment: It's for what you do in that IDE.
Each project in it will be able to find and use the libraries, but if you create a build and try to run the jar outside of the IDE, it might not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784783/what-happens-when-add-to-classpath-in-eclipse-or-intellij/63122747#63122747 Also, Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784783/what-happens-when-add-to-classpath-in-eclipse-or-intellij/63122747#63122747

Answer (score 1):

When you add jars to classpath, your application starting with this jars in `-cp(classpath)` argument. And you will not get ClassNotFoundException when use classes from external jars, that you add to classpath of your project.

When you create web application, jars that you add to classpath, will copy to *lib* folder of installed application and load by jmv that start your web application.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation for the web application.

Answer (score 1):

you get the file name,
When you add jars to classpath, your application starting with this jars in -cp(classpath) argument. And you will not get ClassNotFoundException when use classes from external jars, that you add to classpath of your project.

When you create web application, jars that you add to classpath, will copy to lib folder of installed application and load by jmv that start your web application.
As you can see in this answer